# Cannot inject @Test annotated Method in TestNG

Tags: java, testing, testng

I have implemented following test method, it hasn't any parameters.

```
@Test(groups={"Regression"})
public void send() throws GeneralLeanFtException, InterruptedException {
    SendMessage up = new SendMessage(browser,logger);
    Assert.assertTrue(up.send());
}
```

I get following error message during `mvn install`:

> [Utils] [ERROR] [Error] org.testng.TestNGException:  Cannot inject
>   @Test annotated Method [send] with [interface
>   com.hp.lft.sdk.web.Browser].

Comment: Try running directly from Terminal:
`java org.testng.TestNG YourTestng.xml`
<br/>
Just extra check: make sure your testng configuration file for your group

`<groups>
        <dependencies>
            <group name="groupName"/>
        </dependencies>
</groups>`

Comment: Catch the exceptions inside your test method. Throwing up exceptions to testNG test runner is gonna create problems in handling.

Comment: @Nityanarayan44 : How do you mean "configuration file for group"? What should I create?

Comment: @Manmohan_singh : If I execute test class directly, isn't there exception to catch.

Comment: @plaidshirt - The exception you shared and the method that you shared don't seem to correlate. Can you please double check and please provide the correct test class and also the complete stacktrace ? Also let us know what version of TestNG you are using.